# Wicket and ajax with Rest service

Tags: wicket, wicket-6, wicket-1.6

Is it possible with Wicket to use AJAX but invoking a webservice from a different domain from the one serving the original page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure! You can do anything in your code.

There is no need to use Wicket Ajax APIs for this. You can use plain Javascript APIs or jQuery, or any other JS library.

Just make sure the REST service defines proper CORS headers, otherwise you won't be able to reach it via Ajax.